# Are there any Env variables automatically set on fargate tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I’d like to be able to detect if my code is running on a fargate task (as opposed to on an EC2 instance) and it would be ideal if I could get the fargate task ID from an env var.

I would then use this info for logging and config.

Many CI environments set some env vars which allow me to detect if my code is in CI.

Does AWS do anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the [ECS metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html) for the `LaunchType` value, which will either be `EC2` or `FARGATE`.

Answer (score 3):

"The following are the available Amazon ECS container agent configuration parameters. There are undocumented variables that the agent uses internally that may be visible but that are not intended for customer use. For more information, see Amazon ECS Container Agent on GitHub."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html